# How to add a hidden field value to QSqlRelationalTableModel during row creation?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm starting out with PyQt5. I've created a simple password management app that has a login page and a password listing page against various URLs. I'm unable to find a way to add the user_id value to the record with QSqlRelationalTableModel before it gets inserted into the DB. This is what I've done so far. Code examples would help me. Thanks.

```
    self.model.beforeInsert.connect(self.beforeInsert)

def addRecord(self):
        """
        Add a new record to the last row of the table.
        """
        last_row = self.model.rowCount()
        self.model.insertRow(last_row)

def beforeInsert(self, record):
        print("[INFO] beforeInsert called", record)
        record.setValue("user_id", 1)
        done = self.model.insertRecord(-1, record)
        # done is False at this point, however record.value("user_id") is 1
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: does the database table have a user_id field? If so, is it somehow restricted by e.g. uniqueness?

Comment: @ChristianKarcher Yes, the table has user_id table. It is defined as a foreign key

Comment: so you want to insert the foreign key into your model?